# How to get SSIS to wait for a file to exist and/or become available

Tags: ssis

Scenario:
Package#1 creates a flat file that contains multiple messages (one per line) that is dropped in an external system's "INPUT" folder. The file is picked up by the external system and processed and the responses are written in the same format to a file in the "OUTPUT" folder. The file starts to be written  while the external system is still processing messages, so it is written as foo.rsppro. When processing is complete and all response messages are written it is renamed foo.rsp.

I need to pick up that file once it is complete (i.e. after the rename) and process using Package#2, which will start immediatly following Package#1. When Package#2 starts, the external system could be in three states:

1. Processing the first message not yet complete and no response file written yet, in which case I need to wait for foo.rsppro to be written, then renamed to foo.rsp
2. Processing in progress and foo.rsppro written, in which case I need
   to wait for foo.rsppro to be renamed to foo.rsp
3. Processing completed, foo.rsppro has been written and been renamed to foo.rsp, in which case I just need to process foo.rsp.

I have tried:

1. using a [file in use task](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2012/01/custom-ssis-component-file-in-use-task.html) but that errors if the expected file isn't present when the task begins (i.e. errors for scenario 1 and 2)
2. using a [file watcher task](http://www.konesans.com/products/file-watcher-task.aspx) but that appears to ignore file renames by design, so will never handle scenario 1 or 2

Aside from building a [script task](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/05/wait-until-file-is-unlocked.html), is there a custom task that will handle all three scenarios?

Edit: SSIS 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only a script task can help in your case.

consider using FileSystemWatcher within the script if possible or have an application/windows service which can monitor file system using FileSystemWatcher and invoke your packages when the event is triggered.

Comment: I gave up in the end and wrote a script. Actually two scripts. One looking for .rsppro or .rsp to log that processing has started and one that just looks for .rsp to log that processing has finished. variables are used to determine the wait interval and how many times to check.

Comment: that serves your purpose. what do you use within your scripts to look for the files? Busy loops?

Answer (score 0):

humm, it seems that you can solve it by using a for each loop container on the output folder and set it to read only .rsp files. That would deal with your .rsp files.

how can scenario 1 and 2 happens if package 2 will only run after package1 is finish? As I understand, package1 renames the file so it will only end when all the files are processes and renamed

EDIT:

ok, no worry, there is a solution for everything.
How about, you create a variable on package1 called @TotalNumberOfFiles with the total number of files to be processed, then you use package one to call pacakge2 (not sure if you are doing this already, but if not is very simple, just use a execute pacakge task) and on package2 you create a "parent package variable" (this is very simple too in case you have never done it) and package 2 just start processing when there are @TotalNumberOfFiles files on the output folder with the .rsp extension?

EDIT2:
I dont know jf there is a command to get that, maybe google it, but if you dont find out you can add a foreachloop container pointing to the output directory and do something like this on a script task:

```
Public Sub Main()
        Dts.Variables("User::filesCount").Value = Dts.Variables("User::FilesCount").Value + 1
        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
    End Sub
```

after it finishes counting, just compare with TotalNumberOfFiles. If equal, move to the next task, else sleep for a while and count again

Comment: no, the external system renames the file. The problem is that package#2 starts straight after package#1 finishes, but the external system could be in one of the three states described and I can't find an existing file watcher type task that will handle all three.

Comment: ok, and do you have access to this external system? to change something if necessary

Comment: no, we don't have any way of changing the processing in the external system. The scenario is fixed and SSIS needs to work around it.

Comment: "just start processing when there are @TotalNumberOfFiles files on the output folder with the .rsp extension" and the crux of my question is, how do I do this without a script task?

Comment: btw, the packages are both called by a parent package, one after the other. I don't have any problem passing variables between each package. Also, there is only one message file written and one response file to pick up.

Comment: Why would you not do this using a Script Task?

Answer (score 0):

Final code used as follows. Basically loops through until either the file is found or the max specified number of attempts is hit. 
`Imports System.Threading` is required for `Thread.sleep`. It may not be the most processor efficient method but this is 100% dedicated hardware and the packages is are running in serial.

```
'loop until number of required attempts is hit or file is found
        Do Until iCounter = iAttempts Or bFileFound = True

            'Check if the file exists
            If File.Exists(sFilename) Then

                'Switch bFileFound to true
                bFileFound = True

                'Report that file has been found to VERIFY_Input_File_Exists_INT variable
                Dts.Variables("VERIFY_Input_File_Exists_INT").Value = True

                Dts.Events.FireInformation(1, "DEBUG:", sFilename & " found successfully.", "", 0, False)

            Else

                'sleep for specified time
                Thread.Sleep(iInterval * 1000)

                Dts.Events.FireInformation(1, "DEBUG:", sFilename & " not found successfully. Sleeping for " & iInterval & "* 1000", "", 0, False)

            End If

            'increment counter
            iCounter = iCounter + 1

        Loop
```